# What is the object on the front of Larson and Edwards' calculus and pre-calculus textbooks called?

Tags: surfaces

There is this incredible glass figure on the front of my Calculus textbook, I searched online for what this figure is called and the formula for creating it, but I can't find it. I think it is a variation of the Klein Bottle.

Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: Could it be just a more elabourate mobius strip?

Comment: Looks like a fancy glass/metal Mobius Strip: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip

Answer (score 8):

It looks like an [umbilic torus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbilic_torus):

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/12/Umbilic_Torus.png

<sup>From Wikipedia.</sup>

[Zev Chonoles pointed out another cover](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335319/what-is-the-object-on-the-front-of-larson-and-edwards-calculus-and-pre-calculus/1335325#comment2713662_1335325) with the equation for the umbilic torus:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're right: in the latest edition [they have the parametric equation for the umbilic torus on the cover](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ppuZ0.jpg), and presumably they've kept the same shape on every edition. (Interestingly, the Wikipedia article cites Larson and Edwards for that parametric equation.)

Comment: @ZevChonoles Cool; I had checked other versions of the textbook but I hadn't seen that one.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me to be a **thickened** (and rather heavily stylized) Möbius strip, i.e., a torus with square cross section that is given a one-half twist.

[image]

I made this image just now using the code from my math.SE question, *[Drawing a thickened Möbius strip in Mathematica](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/41856/264)*

Comment: It appears that the Larson shape has three sides, not four. That would make it a triangular cross-section, not a square one. I don't see how one could consider a triangular cross section to be any kind of Mobius Strip.